# count down for gaming

Tags: c#

I need a (possibly) simple code to do count down during a game. I can NOT use methods that lock up the thread, such as

```
Thread.Sleep();
```

In particular I want to create a time limit for the player that must press a sequence of keys. If the player doesn't do it within 10 seconds, it loses!

Answer (score 1):

Taken from MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149618.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

```
public void StartTimer(int dueTime)
{
    Timer t = new Timer(new TimerCallback(TimerProc));
    t.Change(dueTime, 0);
}

private void TimerProc(object state)
{
    // The state object is the Timer object.
    Timer t = (Timer) state;
    t.Dispose();
    Console.WriteLine("The timer callback executes.");
}
```

Comment: I need to interrupt the count down when the player press a key, but this code is used creating a new istance of a class. I have to use the timer in a static method within a static class, so it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer1.Interval=10 * 1000;//ten seconds
timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
timer1.Start();

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //do whatever you want 

}
```